# How would I copy multiple hidden inputs values with multiple IDs with 1 or 2 JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, onclick

I am trying to refactor some of my code. Essentially I am using an button onClick event to invoke a function that copies a hidden input value by its element id. Since I have so many buttons(nearly 30) I am trying to condense all of these functions down to 1 or 2 instead of having a unique function for each unique ID. Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
  <input class="input" type="hidden" value="Test" id="accept1"  size="1" on style="opacity:0">
  <button onclick= "acceptFunction1()" > Test </button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function acceptFunction1() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("accept1");
  copyText.type = 'text';
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  copyText.type = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the name of the field(s) that you want to operate on.  An example might be:

```
<input class="input" type="hidden" value="Test" id="accept1"  size="1" on 
  style="opacity:0">
<button onclick= "acceptFunction('accept1')" > Test </button>

function acceptFunction(fldName) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(fldName);
  copyText.type = 'text';
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  copyText.type = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, such a simple solution I am kicking myself for not thinking of it myself. :D